# Can't send win+s in Autohotkey

Tags: debugging, autohotkey

In some of my scripts, I try to use "send #s" to initiate Cortana for searching. Sometimes it works, but most of time it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong? Here is the script.

Autohotkey 1.1.30.03

Windows 10.0.17763 home edition

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; A window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a match.
;maximize/minimize skype, and open skype if it's closed. 
    +f12::
        if (!winexist("Skype")){ ;start skype for the first time. 
            ;msgbox skype isn't opened
            startskype()
            return
        }
        winget, winstate, MinMax, Skype ; 1 stands for maximized; 0 is neither minimized nor maximized; -1 is minimized. 
        ;msgbox % winstate
        if (winstate = 1){
            msgbox skype is maximized. 
            WinMinimize Skype
        } else if (winstate = 0){
            msgbox skype is neither minimized nor maximized.
            WinActivate Skype ;not working
        ;   winMaximize AutoHotkey Help ;working well
            winMaximize Skype   ;not working for only Skype
        ;   PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF030,,, Skype ;not working 
        } else if (winstate = -1){
            msgbox skype is minimized.
            winmaximize Skype
            ;startskype()
        }
        return 
    ; a function to run skype
        startskype(){
            send #s
            winwaitactive ahk_exe SearchUI.exe  
            sendsleep("skype",200)
            sendsleep("{enter}",3000)
            sendsleep("^{tab}",500) ;next conversation
            send ^+k ;start the video chat
        }
;send a key then sleep for x mount of millisecond
sendsleep(char:="", millisecond:=0, times:=1){
    loop %times% {
        send % char 
        sleep % millisecond
    }
}
```

And this is the result I get:

```
003: SendMode,Input
004: SetWorkingDir,%A_ScriptDir%
008: SetTitleMatchMode,2
014: Return (2.94)
015: if (!winexist("Skype"))  
017: startskype()  
039: Send,#
040: WinWaitActive,ahk_exe SearchUI.exe (76.92)
```

Comment: Try using [WinWait](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm) and [WinWaitActive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm) with Timeout and ErrorLevel before sending commands to a window using the appropriate [Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) command.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try now.

Comment: @user3419297 I changed the `WinWaitActive` line to `WinWaitActive,ahk_exe SearchUI.exe,,5`. But still the Cortana window didn't show up.

Comment: Works on my PC, maybe it's a permission issue? Try running as administrator, or see if any other script is using the `#s`.